# Using Rails how to find booked classes from a user in a given period of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where I post school classes and users can book classes. Now I have added stripe payments, with a monthly subscription. I would like to know how to show users how many classes they have booked since their monthly payment started.

I have tried this:

```
<%= @mylessons_lessons.count %>
```

But this only gives me the total lessons (classes) someone has booked since the beginning of time.

How could I find the booked lessons from each user depending on the date their subscription started and that only takes into account those of the last monthly subscription.

This is my lessons controller:

```
class LessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :mylessons]
  before_action :authenticate_user!


  # GET /lessons
  # GET /lessons.json
  def index
    @lessons = Lesson.order(created_at: :asc)
  end

  # GET /lessons/1
  # GET /lessons/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /lessons/new
  def new
    @lesson = current_user.lessons.build
    redirect_to root_path, warning: "You are not authorized" unless @current_user.admin?
  end

  # GET /lessons/1/edit
  def edit
    redirect_to root_path, warning: "You are not authorized" unless @current_user.admin?
  end

  # POST /lessons
  # POST /lessons.json
  def create
    @lesson = current_user.lessons.build(lesson_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.save
        format.html { redirect_to @lesson, notice: 'lesson was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @lesson }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /lessons/1
  # PATCH/PUT /lessons/1.json
  def update
    redirect_to root_path, warning: "You are not authorized" unless @current_user.admin?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @lesson.update(lesson_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @lesson, notice: 'lesson was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @lesson }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @lesson.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /lessons/1
  # DELETE /lessons/1.json
  def destroy
    redirect_to root_path, warning: "You are not authorized" unless @current_user.admin?
    @lesson.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to lessons_url, notice: 'lesson was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  # Add and remove lessons to mylessons
  # for current_user
  def mylessons
    type = params[:type]

    if type == "add"
      current_user.mylessons_additions << @lesson
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "#{@lesson.title} ha sido añadida a tus clases"

    elsif type == "remove"
      current_user.mylessons_additions.delete(@lesson)
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "#{@lesson.title} ha sido eliminada de tus clases"
    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to lesson_path(@lesson), notice: "Parece que no ha sucedido nada, prueba otra vez!"
    end

  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_lesson
      @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:title, :description, :teacher, :thumbnail, :user_id, :date, :datetime, :lessonlink, :giphyimage, :game, :externalmaterial, :lessonage )
    end
end
```

and my mylessons controller:

```
class MylessonsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :mylessons, :lessons]
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @mylessons_lessons = current_user.mylessons_additions
    @lessons = Lesson.order(created_at: :asc)
  end
end
```

and the schema from my db payments:

```
  create_table "pay_charges", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "owner_id"
    t.string "processor", null: false
    t.string "processor_id", null: false
    t.integer "amount", null: false
    t.integer "amount_refunded"
    t.string "card_type"
    t.string "card_last4"
    t.string "card_exp_month"
    t.string "card_exp_year"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "owner_type"
    t.index ["owner_id"], name: "index_pay_charges_on_owner_id"
  end

  create_table "pay_subscriptions", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "owner_id"
    t.string "name", null: false
    t.string "processor", null: false
    t.string "processor_id", null: false
    t.string "processor_plan", null: false
    t.integer "quantity", default: 1, null: false
    t.datetime "trial_ends_at"
    t.datetime "ends_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string "status"
    t.string "owner_type"
  end

  create_table "plans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "amount", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "interval"
    t.jsonb "details", default: {}, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "trial_period_days", default: 0
  end
```

Comment: Have you read thru the guides on querying, it is all very well explained there https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Yes I read it, but couldn't find how to count for the last month of something (in this case the subscription period). I am new in rails sorry if its something obvious ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually the steps are:

- check when user (paied) subscribed
- get all classes from the date of subscription
- show classes or number of classes in your view

You could use a `scope` in the model you want to check for start date of subscription, something like

```
scope :classes_after_subscription, ->(date) { where("created_at >= ?", date) }
```

and call it in your controller or in a decorator to use it in a view

```
classes_after_subscription("pass_user_sub_date_HERE").size
```

Comment: when I add this to the model mylessons or plan (the stripe one) I get this:
`undefined method classes_after_subscription' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: The scope needs to be in model 'my_lessons' if you have one called after this. So you get all lessons starting from the date of subscription. Then in your controller it should be: @mylessons_lessons = current_user. classes_after_subscription(current_user.subscription_date).size
Try to adapt to your use case, i don't know all your code/names